# auto-fill javascript/applescript accuweather (noob)

Tags: javascript, applescript, autofill

I haven't done any real programming since my university days and even then, it was fortran and pascal (yes, I'm dating myself...), so applescript and javascript are quite foreign to me and I'm probably jumping into the deep end, but why not, right?

I'm currently in the process of looking for jobs in various cities across the USA and I thought it would be a good learning opportunity (and a project to keep my mind sharp) to "automate" the process of adding new cities and use the weather as an ice-breaker in conversations with various HR/hiring managers.  You can sign up for Accuweather email alerts at [accuweather email alerts](http://www.accuweather.com/alerts/index.asp) which seems like a nice feature.

I'm having trouble assigning the value for the zip code and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  When I inspect the website I see the following:

```
<input name="wxzip" type="text" value="" style="width:60px;font-size:12px;
color:#444444;border:1px solid #000000" onchange="verifyZip();
" id="userZipSelection">
```

I've tried the following methods in Applescript to set the zip code value using snippets of JS code.

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('userZipSelection').value = 60015;" in document 1
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('wxzip')[0].value = 60015" in document 1
do JavaScript "document.getElementsById('userZipSelection')[0].value = 60015;" in document 1
do JavaScript "document.regform.wxzip.value = 60015;" in document 1
```

None of these seem to work at setting the zip code.  BTW, in final form, I will get the zip code from a list, but for simplicity I'm setting the value directly in this example.

In the code on the website, there are lots of other places where zip code is referenced, but I don't understand all of the other uses.  For example:

```
if (document.regform.wxzip.value.length != 5)
```

I would greatly appreciate any/all advice on what I'm doing wrong w/r/t setting the value of the zip code.

Thanks.

---

---

With help from adayzdone below, I've fumbled my way to the solution.  Here is the final working code:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "h@t@t@p://www.accuweather.com/alerts/index.asp"
    delay 3
    tell current tab of window 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('userZipSelection').value=12345"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value = 'junk@email.com'"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('getforecast')[0].checked = true"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('getsevere')[0].checked = true"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('format')[0].value = 'html'"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('getupdates')[0].checked = true"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('hours1')[0].value = 10"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('hours2')[0].value = 19"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('days')[1].checked = true"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('days')[2].checked = true"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('days')[3].checked = true"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('days')[4].checked = true"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('days')[5].checked = true"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('days')[6].checked = true"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('days')[0].checked = true"
        do JavaScript "document.regform.submit()"
    end tell
end tell
```

It seems the issue was related to adding the "current tab of window 1" bit.  Can anyone explain why this resolved my issue?

Now I just need to change everything to a variable that I can more readily change to finish the project.

Comment: I tried the first one and it worked. Are you sure accuweather.com is the frontmost safari tab, when you run the code?

Comment: User309603, yes, you're right, the first one does not cause an error when it runs, but I don't see the zip code appearing in the web form.  Shouldn't I be able to see it working?

Comment: I can see it immediately. You may have a weird security setting in Safari. Try to run the script in Chrome/Iron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me...

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell current tab of window 1
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('userZipSelection').value='12345'"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks adayzdone, but why don't I see the zip code appear in the web form?

Comment: adayzdone, you figured it out, it was something with the "current tabs of window 1" that made things work.  Here is the working code.

Comment: Why did the addition of the "current tab of window 1" solve the issue I was having making this code work?